# How to keep four corners of windows form visible all time on desktop?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form which I am using as a desktop application.
Now I want that the form should not go outside desktop borders when I drag it.
I know that the whole window doesnt disappear but I want to display all four corners.
I have set the "border style = Fixed Tool window",and coded to move form programmatically.

So instead of this:

```
----------------------
!                    !
!          ---------------
!          !             !
!          !             !
!          ---------------
!                    !
----------------------
```

I want this:

```
------------------------
!                      !
!         -------------!
!         !           !!
!         !           !!
!         -------------!
!                      !
------------------------
```

Comment: images are not displayed correctly Plz avoid them Thanks

Comment: exactly what am I looking at here?

Comment: I would disagree with changing the behavior of Windows as the user expects it. Normally, the user can slide the window off the screen (or move it to another screen) and changing that behavior might upset the user. So, I wouldn't do it unless there was a very good reason to change the expected behavior of windows on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`LocationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged.aspx) event and compare it to `Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds` this is the primary monitor, if you have multiple monitors you could change then index to select which screen you limit your form to.

```
private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((this.Left + this.Width) > Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Width)
        this.Left = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Width - this.Width;

    if (this.Left  < Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Left)
        this.Left = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Left;

    if ((this.Top + this.Height) > Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Height)
        this.Top = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Height - this.Height;

    if (this.Top < Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Top)
        this.Top = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds.Top;
}
```

Comment: For multiple monitors, you can use `Screen.FromHandle(Handle)` to use the screen the window is currently in.

Comment: @MarkHall This is thowing stackover flow exception when my form object is static in winforms application.

Comment: @theburningfire  make sure you are not recursively calling the function.

Comment: @MarkHall but this will be recursively called because when even left will be set to value this Form1_LocationChanged method will be called.

Answer (score 2):

Compare the forms bounds with [SytemInformation.VirtualScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen.aspx)

Example:

```
    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        KeepBounds();
    }

    private void KeepBounds()
    {
        if (this.Left < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left)
            this.Left = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Left;

        if (this.Right > SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Right)
            this.Left = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Right - this.Width;

        if (this.Top < SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top)
            this.Top = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Top;

        if (this.Bottom > SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Bottom)
            this.Top = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Bottom - this.Height;
    }
```

this will keep the 'four' corners of a form in screen

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question good.

You want to avoid that you window (winforms MainForm) does not leave the screen?
If this is the case, can't you handle this within the event Move of the Form
and while moving check the Top en Left property if those become negative return the method.
And if you know how large the your form is and you resolution you can calculate the right and bottom.

```
private void Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var f = sender as Form;

        var l = f.Left;
        var t = f.Top;

        var h = f.Height;
        var w = f.Width;
        var sh = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height;
        var sw = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Width;
        if(t<0 || t+h > sh) return;
        if (l < 0 || l+w > sw) return;
    }
```

Something like this. **Not tested.**